# Casting classes

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

I have 2 classes:

public class ClassA

public class ClassB (from another namespace) : ClassA

I use method at ClassA

```
public static ClassA Deserialize(string path)
{
ClassA classA;

//classA=code...

return classA;
}
```

I invoke this method at classB

```
public void DoSomething()
{
ClassB classB=(ClassB)ClassA.Deserialize("c:\directory\file.xml);
}
```

method deserialize works, but i get error that cannont cast ClassA to ClassB.

How to deal with this?

```
 public static ClassA DeserializeFromXml(string path)
        {

 XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA));
            ClaasA h;

            TextReader r = new StreamReader(path);


                h = (ClassA)s.Deserialize(r);

                r.Close();

                return h;
}
```

Maybe something with deserialize(string path, Type objectType ) ??

I could can change method Deserialize if it would necessary

Comment: Please provide the code inside Deserialize()
IF you are creating an instance of object of ClassA with classA constructor you will definitely get an error on runtime

Comment: idea with string path, Type objectType is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **isn't** a B. B **is** an A

(ClassB) something_that_is_A cannot be done unless it is a B or a derivative of it.

Answer (score 2):

Without showing your `Deserialize` code it's pretty hard to say what's going on. This is likely to be the heart of the problem - you need to make `Deserialize` actually create an instance of `ClassB` (or a derived class) if you want to be able to cast the result to `ClassB`. If your `Deserialize` method creates an instance of `ClassA` and then sets a bunch of properties, you'll need to either change it or find another way of creating a `ClassB` instance later.

You can only an expression cast to `ClassB` if the value is a reference to an actual instance of `ClassB`. If the object is only an instance of `ClassA` then you won't be able to cast - what would you expect to happen to any extra fields etc in `ClassB`? Unless a user-defined conversion,  casting for a reference type only performs a *reference conversion* - it doesn't create a new object. (See [Eric Lippert's blog post on representation and identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx#) for more details.)

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a void, therefore you trying to cast the return of void to be ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Having `ClassB` inherit from `ClassA` does not allow a `ClassA` object to be cast into a `ClassB` object, as all ClassA objects are not inevitably `ClassB`objects.

If you want to know if your deserialized object is a ClassB object, you can use this code :

```
ClassA a = ClassA.Deserialize("c:\directory\file.xml");

ClassB b = a as ClassB;
```

If the object isn't a `ClassB` instance, b will be null. Otherwise you will have your instance as a `ClassB` object.